# GUID of SharePoint Objects

Tags: sharepoint-server, guid

Is GUID of SharePoint Objects globally unique? Or is there any case where it could be duplicated?

Comment: are you talking of uniqueId?

Comment: yes, example: 89b66b71-afc8-463f-b5ed-9770168996a6 (Guid)

Answer (score 4):

#### GUID

The **G** in GUID stands for **Globally**

The **U** in GUID stands for **Unique**

The **ID** in GUID stands for **Identifier**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier

And yes there is a [once in a 30 octillion chance](http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-UUID-and-GUID) it is not unique

What is an [octillion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_large_numbers) ?? I don't know..

But it sounds huge, and maybe a good lock-out period (*in milliseconds, we should not be too harsh*) on StackOverflow for people who ask questions without searching Google first.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft guarantees you uniqueness inside a SharePoint-Database, not more and not less. Even considering it is a very small possibility to have duplicates, it is possible if you have multiple databases inside the same farm.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.uniqueid.aspx